# Inbox should say what tag wiki I edited

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

If a suggested edit by me to a post is approved, I get a message saying it got approved and what post it was:

[image: +2 What European countries have secret voting within the Legislature?]

If a suggested edit by me to a tag wiki is approved, I get this unspecific message (and a lot of the time I get five or four at a time):

[image: +2 Tag Wiki suggested edit was approved]

It'd be useful to easily see which one was approved, so I can more quickly tell what sort of edits are good.

For consistency's sake with post edits and for usability, I think that it should look more like this, specifying *what* was edited:

[image: +2 [Preguntas] tag wiki suggested edit was approved]

Comment: @Sonic how are you so good at finding duplicates? :P

Comment: This one actually showed up in the "Related" bar.