# In the notification from when our suggested tag wiki edit got approved, include the name of the tag

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications, tag-wiki, achievements-dialog

Currently, when your edit to a post is approved, you'll get a notification in your achievements tab that displays a *"+2"* followed by the title of the post. For example:

> +2 [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/773001)

But when a tag wiki edit gets approved, the notification only displays

> [Tag Wiki suggested edit was approved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/fun/info)

Can we get the name of the tag *(where our wiki edit got approved)* into the description of the notification?

Comment: I think this was [first asked in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84893/323179) but I prefer keeping the new, updated question here open.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Inbox should say what tag wiki I edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330159/inbox-should-say-what-tag-wiki-i-edited) (From 2019)

Comment: @Laurel: The same question was asked [3 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330159/inbox-should-say-what-tag-wiki-i-edited) and was closed as a duplicate of the question you linked.